# SUMY Text Summarizer fails to summarize and returns original text

Tags: python, text, summarization

```
LANGUAGE = "english"
stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)

def get_luhn_summary(text):
        summ = list()
    
        parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(text, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
        summarizer = LuhnSummarizer()
        summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)
    
        for sentence in summarizer(parser.document,10):
            summ.append(str(sentence))
        return summ

summaryA_luhn = get_luhn_summary(textA)
```

Always returns the original string. I am confused cause I am following the documentation to the t

Answer (score 0):

The summarization is done by sentence count.

```
import nltk
from sumy.parsers.plaintext import PlaintextParser
from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
from sumy.summarizers.luhn import LuhnSummarizer as Summarizer
from sumy.nlp.stemmers import Stemmer
from sumy.utils import get_stop_words

LANGUAGE = "english"
SENTENCES_COUNT = 2
nltk.download('punkt')

parser = PlaintextParser.from_file("document.txt", Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))

stemmer = Stemmer(LANGUAGE)

summarizer = Summarizer(stemmer)
summarizer.stop_words = get_stop_words(LANGUAGE)

for sentence in summarizer(parser.document, SENTENCES_COUNT):
    print(sentence)
```

The following will read sentences from file name document.txt and based on SENTENCES_COUNT it will summarize based on the number of sentences you specify.

So if document.txt has 10 sentences and you set SENTENCES_COUNT = 2 you will get a summarization of two sentences.

You can also simply swap out:

```
parser = PlaintextParser.from_file("document.txt", Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
```

with:

```
text = "This is the string to parse. Hopefully it will be more than one sentence. Like so!"    
parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(text, Tokenizer(LANGUAGE))
```

If you what to parse from string instead of a file.